# What does Y-axis of Normal Distribution's plot denote?

Tags: normal-distribution

As we know that in case of the continuous random variable, the probability of observing a single point (say `x`) is zero. But at the same time, we have the formula for `N(mean, var)` where N denotes a normal distribution. But if I put `x` in `N(mean, var)`, I will get a non-zero value. Doesn't Y-axis of the curve corresponding to `N(mean, var)` denotes the probability?

Comment: There are many versions of this question on the site. The answer is basically that the Y-axis is not a probability, it is a probability density. The area under the curve makes a probability. If that area is infinitesimally small, then the probability goes to 0 as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Not restricted to normal random variables, $p_X(x)$ represents the *density value*, which can be thought of as a *relative measure* that the random variable equals $x$. It is relative since it can be compared to other values in the domain, but it is not an *absolute measure* of probability since being equal to any specific value has probability $0$. In some analyses, this specific probability can be written as $P(X=x)=p_X(x)dx$.

Answer (score 0):

*I think the confusion comes from the following  - In a histogram the x axis shows the possible outcomes and the y axis shows the number of times each x outcome was observed. If there are N observations in total then dividing each number on the Y axis by N will give you the observed probability that each outcome happened so the histogram can also graph the probability of each x outcome.
Now when we have a continuous distribution the y axis no longer shows a count or a probability. Why not? Well, in a continuous distribution the literal probability that any particular outcome is observed is zero! This seems odd but just remember there are an infinite number of points between 0 and 1 or 1/2 and 1 or 3/4 and 1 etc. so the probability that any individual pt. happens is zero.
Even though the probability of any pt. is zero the probability of observing something within a range is well defined. e.g. if there is an equal probability of observing something between 0 and 1 then the probability of any specific pt. happening is 0 but the probability of a number between 3/4 and 1 happening is 1/4.
Now to answer your question, the normal distribution is defined so that when you integrate or sum the area under the normal distribution between any two points it gives you a probability*

Comment: The relevant way to characterize a histogram is different than yours: in a histogram the *areas* of the rectangles represent probabilities, not the heights.  This is the characterization that generalizes, in the limit where all rectangles shrink to zero in width, to the density function.

Comment: @whuber correct me If I am wrong, for normal frequency histograms, the x-axis represents the buckets and the y-axis represents the number of occurrences right i.e. frequency?

Comment: That's a common misconception--and it leads to the confusion expressed in the question.  In a true histogram, the y-axis is the number of occurrences *per unit of $x.$*  By emphasizing this you don't have to make a conceptual leap when relating the histogram to the density curve.

Comment: Ohh see,thanks for clarifying, @whuber should I remove the answer ? Or can you edit and make it better if possible ?

Comment: It's up to you.  I think your post holds out the possibility of being very helpful once this issue is clarified.